# Racket Tree Depth function (tree recursion) (No Structure Nodes!)

Tags: tree, scheme, racket, depth

I'm trying to write a procedure (depth tree) that takes a tree as input and return an integer
indicating the maximum level of the tree using Racket/Scheme

Example:

```
(depth '()) => 0
(depth '(1 2 3)) => 1
(depth '(a (b (c (d))))) => 4
(depth '((((((0))))))) => 6
```

I can't use structures in doing this, so it makes it a much more complicated task for me.
I've tried using car/cdr recursion + and to do this, but I can't quite get it right.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to share what you have tried and the specific error encountered.

Answer (score 1):

An input is an atom or a pair; if the input is a pair then it may contain either atoms or more pairs. When the input is a pair, you should add 1 to the maximum nesting level of the sub-pairs. Otherwise the input is not a pair, and the maximum nesting level is 0. Note that in Racket, `'()` is not a `pair?`.

These observations lead to a very simple definition:

```
#lang racket

(define (max-depth xss)
  (if (pair? xss)
      (+ 1 (apply max (map max-depth xss)))
      0))
```

Here, `(map max-depth xss)` evaluates to a list of the maximum nesting levels of all sublists within `xss`. To find the maximum, `apply` is needed to apply `max` to the list of arguments. Since the sublists themselves are already nested one level deep, 1 is added to the maximum.

```
max-depth.rkt> (max-depth 'x)
0
max-depth.rkt> (max-depth '())
0
max-depth.rkt> (max-depth '(1 2 3))
1
max-depth.rkt> (max-depth '(a (b (c (d)))))
4
max-depth.rkt> (max-depth '((((((0)))))))
6
max-depth.rkt> (max-depth '(a b (c d (e f (g)) h) (i j) (k (l (m (n (o) p))) q) r))
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up for this problem:

- If the input is not an empty list, then using `map`, we can (recursively) check the maximum depth of recursion for each element in the list, and choose  from the *list that the* `map` *outputs*, the element which has the greatest maximum depth of recursion and add 1 to it.
- else if the input is the empty list, we return 0.

The code:

```
(define (depth tree)
  (if (null? tree)
      0
      (max-items (map (lambda (x)
                        (cond ((not (pair? x)) 1)
                              (else (+ 1 (depth x))))) tree))))

(define (max-items items)
  (define (iter lst cur-max)
    (cond ((null? lst) cur-max)
          ((> (car lst) cur-max) (iter (cdr lst) (car lst)))
          (else (iter (cdr lst) cur-max))))
 (iter (cdr items) (car items)))
```